# Silverstripe 3, ProductCatalog - friendly URL and Sub Categories

Tags: php, friendly-url, silverstripe, product, catalog

I am creating a product catalog using this Silverstripe Module:

https://github.com/luisdias/silverstripe-productcatalog
Which is based on this module 
https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObject-as-Page

I have an issue that friendly URLs are appearing as: www.mysite.com/product-page/category/**1**
or
www.mysite.com/product-page/show/**1/1** as apposed to their title or url segment. www.mysite.com/product-page/show/**my-category/my-product**

I've tried changing the code from Product.php to

```
//Return the link to view this category
public function Link() {
    $Action = 'show/' . $this->ID . '/' . $this->URLSegment;
    return $Action;    
}
```

from

```
//Return the link to view this category
public function Link() {
    $Action = 'show/' . $this->ID . '/' . $this->CategoryID;
    return $Action;    
}
```

Which works, but not for the category titles and is the url has spaces it generates %20 instead of _.

It seems like a simple change which I can't work out..

---

I also want to be able to have sub-categories. So everything in a category can be divided into say their "Size". At present All products are divided just once. Products > Categories I would like Products > Categories > Sub-Categories can any one help me achieve this? thanks

Comment: The _Product Catalog_ module is not based on the _DataObjectAsPage_ module.

Answer (score 2):

### 1) For the spaces in the URL issue:

URLSegment is a field on the product DataObject which is manually entered in the CMS, correct? If so, you'll have to type in the URLSegment as a URL friendly string, something like `my-awesome-product`.

If you want the URLsegment auto-generated, the [DataObject As Page module you mentioned handles that](https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObject-as-Page/blob/4f2cb29a23b71a2649c2edeaf565945bf5dd985b/code/DataObjects/DataObjectAsPage.php#L471-L494). I would add that method, and the associated `onBeforeWrite` method to a `DataObject` that extends `Product`. You may be able to accomplish this with some [`DataExtension`](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension) magic.

### 2) For the category URLSegment in the URL issue:

You'll have to overload the [`Link()`](https://github.com/luisdias/silverstripe-productcatalog/blob/e093dd583d14dcad7ad1b91ade9469584c925c37/code/Category.php#L64-L68) method on your `Category` class as well. You'll need to change that (or overload that method in a custom `DataObject` that extends `Category`):

```
$Action = 'category/' . $this->URLSegment;
```

And add the `generateURLSegment` method and `onBeforeWrite` call as you did in #1.